# findstr is not recognized when trying to start Jboss server

Tags: jboss

I've downloaded Jboss jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6.zip file and extracted the zip. Then I've set system variable JBOSS_HOME=F:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2. When I'm trying to run the jboss by double click on run.bat it executes for a while and then windows are automatically closed. If I run the run.bat file from command prompt it shows the error depicted below:[image]

I am not able to find out where is the problem, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have a look at this JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/FindstrCommandNotFound)

The problem is findstr is not in your path, set it and restart command prompt .

You can set path containing findstr to rid out of this.
[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) is material how to set path

Comment: @sam is it solved? , let me know. and you can always upvote or accept it as answer if its the case

Comment: i see that links and tried that but it not work for me problem is same.

Comment: @sam problem is clear , findstr exec is not in your path, can you post me your path variable info

Comment: please explain where i found path variable info?

Comment: @sam , i have updated answer, set c:\windows\system32 in to your path. [if current win is in C]